# Smali function: Return an Integer

Tags: android, apk, smali

I know how to return a TRUE boolean from a function:

```
.locals 1
const/4 v0, 0x1
return v0
```

Now I need to return an integer (10000 value). How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following method

```
public int return1000() {
    int i = 1000;
    return i;
}
```

Looks like this in *smali*

```
.method public return1000()I
    .locals 1

    .prologue
    .line 278
    const/16 v0, 0x3e8

    .line 279
    .local v0, "i":I
    return v0
.end method
```

Comment: This is a useful approach for figuring out any sort of "how do I do [x] in smali" question

Comment: This is how I always do it. Especially if you are trying to inject a lot of code, writing a static method and compiling in Android Studio will generate 99% of what you need for you, then you just need to add the generated smali method/class and modify a line or two in the target smali to hook it in.